# Declaring an Optional Function

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

Is there a convenient way to declare a function name which may, or may not, exist when a program is compiled and run? (The intention is to allow the end-user to provide the function definition, if needed.) The program calls this function, only if it is supplied. For example:

```
(defun baz () t)

(defun foo ()
  (if (fboundp 'bar)
      (bar)
    (baz)))
```

This issues a warning in SBCL. Can the warning be avoided without explicitly suppressing it?

Comment: `(funcall 'bar)`

Comment: That does it! Thanks.